# Zend Framewok installation and configuration error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, configuration

I want to install Zend Framework, this error occurs when I try to open the URL of the project I have created.

```
[Mon Feb 27 08:50:46 2012] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] 
C:/AppServ/www/zf/quickstart/public/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', 
perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats not ZF error. You have to enable apache `rewrite_module` extension in your apache config

Comment: I enable this statement LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so in the http.conf inside the appach but the same problem

Comment: I make restart, this error has gone and another one appear!!
 The error is "You don't have permission to access /zf/quickstart/" !

Comment: You should properly configure ZF and apache maybe create vhost for your app.. but that's other question